# Verify that a mapping is a surjective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to show that mapping

$$\pi: A \times B \to A, \quad (a,b) \mapsto a$$

with kernel {${e_A \times B}$} is a surjective homomorphism (epimorphism).

I looked up the definition of an epimorphism, but it didnt seem to help me in this instace (It was talking about catagory theory).

I know a homomorphism is a mapping such that $\pi(ab)=\pi(a)\pi(b)$
but how does this relate to my problem?

$\pi((a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2))=\pi(a_1,b_1)\pi(a_2,b_2)$?

How could I use the kernel to prove this is a surjective homomorphism?

Thanks!!

Comment: What kind of structures do $A, B, A\times B$ have?

Comment: Structures...Im not sure. My book has never mentioned "structures"...Do you mean $A \timesB={(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),....}&?

Comment: I mean, are they groups, vector spaces, ...?

Comment: they are groups

Comment: those structures are i think componentwise

Comment: Does this definition help you? _A map (for instance a homomorphism) $f:X\to Y$ is called surjective if for every $y\in Y$ we can find an $x\in X $ sucht that $f(x)=y$._

Comment: thanks everyone! I just needed the fact that $\pi((a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2))$ =$\pi(a_1a_2,b_1b_2)$ I had forgotten this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pi((a_1,b_1).(a_2,b_2))=\pi(a_1a_2,b_1b_2)=a_1a_2=\pi((a_1,b_1))\pi((a_2,b_2))$

and

$ker(\pi)$= {$(a,b)\in A \times B \,|\, \pi((a,b))=a= e_A\} \implies ker(\pi) = \{e_A\} \times B$

For any $a$ in $A$, one possible preimage in $A\times B$ is $(a, e_B)$. Thus, $\pi$ is surjective.

Comment: Your last equality looks strange, i think it's a format issue. Also, what about the surjectivity?

Comment: $ker(\pi)$ is the set of all elements in $A\times B$ those are projected on $e_A$. where am i wrong? please let me know

Comment: @ Saikat You are not wrong, I just got confused by the notation (maybe because of the $\implies$ inside of the definition of $ker$). Also, I screwed up editing it! Can you please erase the "$a\in$" in the last line?

Comment: oka.. no problem

Comment: -for $a\in A \exists  (a,e_B)\in A \times B s.t. \pi (a,e_B)=a $

Comment: @dafinguzman people can understand that much :P